# How to calculate and save the largest known prime number?

Tags: python, largenumber

How can I calculate and save `2^74,207,281 − 1` to a text file?

First problem: I get memory errors when I try to print it. How can I determine how much memory I need?

Second problem: How can I calculate it in the fastest time?

Comment: What do you mean "to calculate"? To write all digits of its decimal representation into a text file? Probably, Python is not appropriate for this task, especially if you want "fastest time".

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to save it all into a text file.

Comment: The work has already been done for you: http://www.mersenne.org/primes/digits/M74207281.zip

Comment: @Wolfram Python uses an optimized bignum library written in C. Python is fine for the task.

Comment: @JohnColeman In my console it doesn't print this number and start to eat a lot of CPU.

Comment: @Wolfram *Calculating* the number is easy, *printing* it is hard.

Comment: That's what I  wrote in the first comment, but you answered that Python is fine.

Comment: Your question asks about "save" and "calculate" (not "print").

Comment: @JohnColeman Does the optimized library apply to calculating 2**74207281?

Comment: The gmpy package can do it. See my edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This calculation is pretty fast for me, doesn't give memory errors and is exact:

```
>>> x = 2**74207281 - 1
```

Since:

```
>>> x > 2**74207281
False
>>> x > 2**74207281 - 2
True
```

Just don't try and print it out, that will take ages. Try printing small big numbers to get an idea of how long...

Oh, you want to print it out...

The `gmpy` package has a faster stringification algorithm for its numbers:

```
>>> x = 2**74207281 - 1
>>> import gmpy
>>> xx = gmpy.mpz(x)
>>> s = str(xx) # takes a few seconds.
>>> len(s)
22338618
>>> f = file("/tmp/bigprime.txt","w")
>>> f.write(s)
>>> f.close()
```

The resulting file has 22 million digits:

```
$ wc -c /tmp/bigprime.txt 
22338618 /tmp/bigprime.txt
```

Comment: This is a less than 10MB number, it doesn't take ages. But this should be done on low level-language like C.

Comment: Computing `len(str(2**1000000))` takes a second on my machine, and I imagine printing it out will take a few seconds. But `len(str(2**(10000000)))` (one more zero, but 3,000,000 digits) is beyond my patience. Not sure if python hits a wall at that point...

Comment: Nice suggestion about `gmpy`

Comment: Wow, gmpy is a thing!

Answer (score 2):

The function `pow()` will use exponentiation by squaring and is almost instant:

```
>>> import math
>>> p = pow(2, 74207281) - 1
>>> math.log10(p)
22338617.477665834
```

It thus has 22338618 digits.

Comment: No need to use pow, just `p=2**74207281-1` works. The problem is to print the number, not to store 74207281 one's in the memory.

Comment: On my machine at least, `p=2**74207281-1` is problematic. It doesn't seem to use exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: Strange: `>>> timeit.timeit("x=2**74207281-1")\N
0.013522571996873012`

Comment: @Wolfram Perhaps it depends on the version of Python. It just took Python 2.7 roughly 2 minutes to compute without `pow()` But with `pow()` it is a fraction of a second.

Comment: I checked on 2.7.12 - also almost instantly.

Comment: On 3.5, the `**` operator was taking a while. I interrupted it, and used `math.pow` and it took a fraction of a second... interesting. **EDIT** Whoops! I forgot to assign the result of `2**74207281 - 1` to a variable, so the time it was taking was to print the `repr` to the terminal!

Comment: @Wolfram I also happen to have a 3-year old laptop with somewhat limited RAM. It might also have something to do with hardware support for certain types of calculations. I need a new computer.

Comment: `22338617.477665834` does not contain 22338618 digits, it has 17.

Comment: @Martineau That is the base 10 logarithm of the prime in question (which is the natural antecedent of the pronoun "it")

Comment: @JohnColeman Okay, the RAM maybe a problem then, I don't know. I have 4-year old laptop with Intel Core i7 and ~4 GB RAM, but I don't think that hardware solely would make such a difference.